# How can I simulate join() method with reduce() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, join, reduce

I would like to make a function that does the same that join() method, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((separator, el) => el + separator, separator);
};
console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

it returns 321- instead of 1-2-3

Comment: In `(separator, el) => el + separator`, the argument `separator` is a misnomer. Rename it `joinedStringSoFar`, rename `el` by `currentElement`, and replace `el + separator` by something that makes more sense. `separator` as an _initial value_ also makes no sense: you want `"1-2-3"`, not `"-1-2-3"`, right? How about an empty string? Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and hopefully your mistake will become obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where I've added some logging to the `exampleJoin` function so you can see what it is doing. Then there is a final `join` method at the bottom which is what you are looking for in the end.

```js
const exampleJoin = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el ) => {
    console.log(`string so far: '${acc}', Current element: '${el}'`)
  return acc + el + separator
  }, '');
};

const ret = exampleJoin([1, 2, 3], '-')
console.log(`ret value: ${ret}`)
console.log(`ret value after slice ${ret.slice(0,-1)}`)

const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el ) => acc + el + separator, '').slice(0,-1);
};

console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

The `acc` is the accumulated value so far, `el` is the current element being processed and the empty sting is the initial value off the accumulator `acc`. The slice is to remove the trailing seperator which this method will introduce.

Comment: If you can always ensure that the array will be non-zero length then @Mhmdrz_A 's answer is a bit cleaner as it doesn't need the `slice` at the end. However it will fail on an empty array so it depends on how you are going to be using it. If you are certain of non-zero length strings then use that one. By not specifying an initialValue for the accumulator it uses the first value as the initial value, and then runs the reduce method starting from the second item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce works left to right, but the ordering and naming of your parameters may be leading to confusion.

The reduce callback takes two arguments, where the first argument is 'accumulated value', and the second is the current element of the array. The 'accumulated value' here will be your joined string, so you need to build it up in the right order, starting the string with the first array element and not the separator itself.

So, to accomplish this, avoid using a default value for the `reduce` call, and instead return the joined string (so far) plus the separator plus the current element. Make sure to handle the case of an empty array in some way as well.

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  if (!arr.length) return "";
  return arr.reduce((joined, el) => joined + separator + el);
};
console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

Comment: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is left-to-right, [reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) is right to left

Comment: _“Reduce works right to left”_ — What? No, `reduceRight` works right-to-left. Maybe clarify this part so it doesn’t sound misleading. _“where the first argument is ‘current value’”_ — No, it’s the _aggregated_, or _accumulated_, value. This is easily confused with _“current element of the array”_, so clarify this as well. _“avoid using a default value for the reduce call”_ — No, this is not recommended at all! This will fail for empty arrays. The most sensible initial value is the empty string.

Comment: I would avoid the default value for _this particular_ reduce call. Generally you are right, in most cases it is better to have one. In this instance, it is easy to handle outside of the reduce and using an empty string as an initial value complicates the reduce logic more than just checking for an empty at the start. My bad on the r-t-l though, you should see me try to give driving directions.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed a little tweak:

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + separator + el);
};
console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((r, v) => r+= v + separator, "").slice(0,-1);
};
console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine.

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr, i) => prev + (i != 0 ? '-' : '') + curr, '')
}

console.log(join([1, 2, 3], '-'));
```

Don't forget to check for the index for zero, you don't want the separator to be presented before the first element.